# Locked out of my accord

Tags: honda, electrical, accord

My 2013 Honda Accord EXL the battery died the key fob won't open the door and neither will the manual key what can I do

Comment: Car seems awfully new for the key not to work in the door lock. Have you tried the trunk or your spare key? If none of them work for whatever reason I'd advise calling a tow truck/locksmith that can pop the lock.

Comment: You may want to use Graphit-Spray to make the key working again. See https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/53474/34400.

Answer (score 6):

From underneath the car, you may be able to get access to the starter motor.  It is then possible to connect jump leads from a charged battery to the car by connecting the positive lead to the the large connector on the starter motor and the negative lead to a suitable place on the engine.  Once you have power, you may be able to open the car as usual.

Comment: if you have a factory alarm, might want to be ready for a horn blast when you connect power!

Comment: If it has the 2.4 motor the terminals on the starter are under the intake and aren't accessible.