# Unable to unlock driver's door with key in Toyota Yaris

Tags: toyota, key, locks, door, yaris

I have a Toyota Yaris 1.3 from year 2000. Yesterday I was unable to unlock my driver door - the key won't turn (either direction). The key works on the passenger's side. It's not frozen, temperatures are well above 0 Celsius (32 Fahrenheit).

I read somewhere that Graphite spray can help in this situation:

[image: NIGRIN Graphit-Spray]

Some of the people advised to use WD-40.

Is it safe to use them?

What else could I try?

Comment: So, did you try or you could just replace the lock mechanism...

Comment: I ordered the graphite spray, will try next week. Last option is to swap with passanger side, which is almost never used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise against WD-40. I've never seen it suggested professionally. Graphite is always the preferred choice. Either in spray, or powdered.

The WD-40 will leave a film which can gum up in the future, where Graphite doesn't have this issue.

Cycle the lock/unlock lever inside the vehicle and/or use the lock/unlock button. The door handle isn't connected to the key cylinder, but in some cases is related, so you may want to jiggle the handle, and cycle all of the said components to ensure no other components are sticking, while jiggling and cycling the key.