# Locked out, can I get in through my trunk? 1999 Mercury Sable

Tags: locks, mercury

I *have* the key, but it won't open any of the door locks. Fob and keyless entry won't work, the battery died (yes, I need to get it replaced).

I can probably get into the trunk, a good shove in just the right spot will usually pop the latch on it. Can I get in past the back seat without too much damage, or would it be easier to try and get in through a window (coat hangar, slim Jim etc)??

Comment: Which battery died?  Is it the battery that is stopping you getting in?

Comment: Do you have fold down rear seats?

Comment: If you can get under the car, you can get a +ve jumper cable or battery charger on the start motor post and a -ve cable / jumper onto the engine block, you can get power into it that way that ought to be enough to let you unlock the cabin.

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/25780/locked-out-of-my-accord/25782#25782

Comment: Why does the key not unlock the door? Have you tried spraying the lock with WD-40?

Comment: eeeeek.... please don't spray into the lock with WD-40!

Comment: @elrobis Please explain why.

Comment: @HandyHowie, there's some [discussion on this point here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/6695/what-kind-of-lubrication-should-i-use-for-a-lock), but admittedly it's hard to know the difference between religion and reality on this. Some oppose graphite and favor WD40, others oppose WD40 and favor graphite. I fall into the latter camp. While WD40 is zippity do-da at first, once it ages, just seems to become sticky, and facilitates grit and grime clinging to the internals.

Comment: @elrobis I certainly wouldn't spray graphite into a lock containing electrical components as on a car central locking. Graphite is conductive